# How to build simple XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I'd like to retrieve the connectionString value in the code snippet below.  I've tried several XPaths but always get error or object not found.  I've been using these sites:

```
http://www.xpathtester.com/test
http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx
```

Here's the XPath I've tried:

```
/connectionStrings/add/@connectionString
/connectionStrings/add[@connectionString]
```

Here's the code:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mydb" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably there is a default namespace??? This is the most FAQ for XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your XPath queries are valid. The first one selects the attribute, the second selects an `<add>` element that has a `connectionString` attribute.

What errors do you get, and in what context?

Here's 'proof' that the XPath is fine, using [Ruby](http://ruby-lang.org) with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), which is built on top of libxml2:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML '<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mydb" connectionString="foo" providerName="bar" />
</connectionStrings>'

puts doc.at_xpath('/connectionStrings/add/@connectionString')
#=> foo

puts doc.at_xpath('/connectionStrings/add[@connectionString]')
#=> <add name="mydb" connectionString="foo" providerName="bar"/>
```